# How can I add a texture or better a canvas 2d text to a face of a LatheGeometry?

Tags: textures, three.js

Here is an example of what i'm doing:
http://artlineatvb.it/test_3d/test_09/

I wanna place that text on the external surface of the ring.

I've seen this 
http://enriquemorenotent.com/demos/cube2/
wich does the trick with te cube's faces

If it's not possible i can create an image with the text, but i'm not able to put it on the ring

Thanks!

Comment: I did a little step beyond: http://artlineatvb.it/test_3d/test_10/
but now i don't know how to position it correctly, how to fill exactly the entire ring without stretching the text...
I need help, if there is someone interested in this work, we can pay for it! thank you!